# Why cannot Android allocate 1264 bytes?

Tags: android-memory

A classical error in Android ndk application (using ffmpeg library):
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

I debugged in:
it exits at the command below:

```
ic = av_malloc(sizeof(AVFormatContext));
```

sizeof(AVFormatContext) = 1264. The device is Nexus 4.

So I don't believe it is because of a large size.
Something must happen before to cause it.

Actually a similar application (earlier version without audio stream) works well. The new version adds in the audio stream. All c++ code work well in pure C++ programs.

I suspect Android set a limit before it hits the command which causes error.
Any clue please?

Comment: so is the `ic` variable `NULL` *after* the call to `av_malloc()`?

Comment: It exits to an ffmpeg function related to close the file. I cannot track the variable ic.

Comment: @userXXX Why not? You just stated that you have used a debugger.

Comment: I don't know. Android NDK debugger does not work well. Sometimes I even can't track in. Or maybe the built ffmpeg library does not enable debugging well.

Comment: I tried the option of enabling debugging, when compiling Android ffmpeg library. Now with the new library used, I still cannot track into the ffmpeg code (sometimes can go there for one or two lines). So I suspect we cannot debug Android NDK shared library code.